# Regex to not allow symbols except hypens and underscores

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been trying for ages now using JavaScript to get a regex that does not allow symbols however allows hyphens and underscores but it just isn't working, here is what I have tried:

```
function checkUsername(username)
    {
        username_lbl = document.getElementById('<%= username_lbl.ClientID %>');
        register_btn = document.getElementById('<%= register_btn.ClientID %>');
        if (username.match("?[!@#$%^&*()+=[{]};:<>|./?.]"))
        {
            username_lbl.innerHTML = 'Cannot contain symbols';
            register_btn.disabled = true;
            username_lbl.style.color = "red";
        }
    }
```

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you mean `if (username.match(/[-_]/))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because many of the symbols (e.g. ?, [,] ) are used as a regex symbol. You need to either escape them, or do this:

```
username.match("[^\\w-_]");
```

[^] means does not match character set.

\w means word character [a-zA-Z0-9]

**EdBallot Edit**: Fixed typo regex (was `[^\\w-_]`, changed to `[^\w\-_]`)

**Author Edit**: It should be `"[^\\w-_]"` because it is double quoted and should be escaped, or you can single quote or make it regex

```
username.match(/[^\w-_]/)
```

Comment: There is a typo in the regex. It should be `[^\w\-_]`

Comment: @mogorilla What do you mean does not work? Do you get any error?

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```js
var username = "_Fred-Fred_"; 
if (/[^-_a-zA-Z]/.test(username)) {
  alert("Wrong username: " + username);
}
username = "!_Fred-Fred_"; 
if (/[^-_a-zA-Z]/.test(username)) {
  alert("Wrong username: " + username);
}
```

The `[^-_a-zA-Z]` matches anything but a letter, a hyphen or an underscore. If something else is found, the test is failed.

Comment: If you need to match any Unicode letter, let me know.

Comment: Thank you - saved me some time!